# Strange behavior while dividing i w tagach windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

When I run the following code, it doesn't work (it's not dividing), but return 0 Math.Pow() works.

```
{
    suma = 1;

    foreach (var liczba in Lista_liczb)
    {
        suma = suma*liczba;
        ilosc++;
    }

    var potega = 1/3; //Math.Pow(ilosc,-1);
    double wynik = Math.Pow(suma,potega);
    textBlock2.Text = Convert.ToString(wynik);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this line doesn't work:
var potega = 1/3; //Math.Pow(ilosc,-1);
and I have no idea, what could be the reason
It's just not dividing...

Answer (score 0):

Your `potega` variable is an Int32 (assuming you're using Visual Studio, hover over `var` to check the type), which truncates the result of `1/3`, or 0.3333, to 0.

Either make `potega` a double:

```
double potega = 1 / 3;
```

Or cast one of the numbers to a double first:

```
var potega = 1d / 3;
```